# Issue using Task.Factory.FromAsync

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-ctp, async-await

I enjoyed the new C# 5's **async** and **await** and I want to set it up to one of my previous Tcp application which I used the async whay (not async & await, in fact Begin*, End*)

in my application every message have a response, so every time you use BeginSend, you will receive a message related the message you first sent. (lets suppose command and it's report)

I want to add a new function called **RequestAsync** that you send your message and wait till the response comes. let me show the usage

```
string response = await RequestAsync("hi");
```

on this occasion, you will send a "hi" message and then code waits till the response related to this comes.

I had problems using **Task.Factory.FromAsync**, so I tried the following code, i want to make sure the performance is roughly the same as **TaskFactory** way.

```
public async Task<IRequestResult> SendRequestAsync(IRequest request, string message)
{
        IRequestResult result = BeginSendRequest(request, message);

        while (!result.IsCompleted)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1);
        }

        return result;
}
```

and BeginRequest is my own method.

Sincerely yours,
Peyman Mortazavi

Comment: unrelated, by why using goto (someone might get a minor heart attack just on seeing that), use a while loop instead...

Comment: LOOL, yes i was some kind of foolish really ;) i correct it.

Answer (score 4):

No, that's going to be pretty awful in terms of efficiency - you'll be waking up and requiring rescheduling every 5 milliseconds. You've added latency while you effectively sleep between cycles as well.

You should go back to trying to use `Task.Factory.FromAsync` - you haven't told us what went wrong when you tried that, so it's hard to help you fix it... It's possible that you haven't implemented the asynchronous programming model pattern correctly to start with. (The fact that you're not providing a callback to your `BeginSendRequest` method is suggestive of that.)

I hope your real code doesn't have `catch {}` either...

Comment: I need to share my whole code to provide you the details, let me create a sample code. then ill share it here. thanks

Comment: My problem with TaskFactory is that I use a class called IRequestResult which has the IAsyncResult interface but the Task cannot work cope with it. it will throw RemotingException : The async result object is null or of an unexpected type.

Comment: @Peyman: Can you not add a proxying layer which *does* return `IAsyncResult`? That's still likely to be a lot cleaner than doing it all yourself.

Comment: I don't think, since I send a message with a specific code at the beginning of the message using Socket.BeginSend. then in the OnReceive (this is my async call back of Socket.BeginReceive) I can recognize that code again. in this occasion I will consider the message as the response of the first message. then I will call the callback given to the send request (which is a part of IRequest interface). this is the exact problem why I cannot use TaskFactory. since TaskFactory will not wait till the IRequestResult's IsCompleted property goes to true. it will only check whether it is true or not.

Comment: @Peyman: I'm afraid it's hard to follow your explanation, but I would strongly suggest that you *either* follow the existing pattern *or* rewrite from scratch using other async features. Designing your own pattern (which it sounds like you've done) is a bad idea in terms of consistency with .NET and interoperability with things like `TaskFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

Poling can never be efficient as IO completion ports, and why even use an async method if you are only waiting for it and not doing anything **in the mean time**, it just ads needles overhead.

Comment: because it is easy to use. IRequestResult r = await RequestAsync(); but if there are other efficient ways, I want to implement them, this is why I asked this question when I guess that it is not efficient.